# Help in simple probability question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm a little confused in some simple question in probability theory,

Say that the probability for rain in London in some random day is $P_{rain}$; and the probabilities of rain in one day and another are independent.

We know that the probability for rain in exactly $3$ days of $7$ is $C(7,3) \cdot P_{rain}^3 \cdot(1-P_{rain})^4$.

*Question:* Say that I arrived to London in a rainy day, what's the probability of rain in 3 days of the current week?

Does it equal $C(6,2) \cdot P_{rain}^2 \cdot(1-P_{rain})^4 ? $

$($I think so because of the fact that the probabilities are independent...$)$

Comment: Do you have any prior probablites?

Comment: Uniform probabilty, in the unigram model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have a rainy day . From remaining 6 day , you have to get 2 rainy days . The probabilities of getting 2 days is $C(6,2)= \cdot P_{rain}^2 \cdot(1-p_{rain})^4$